# Change toggle state for multiple elements and need to keep in localstorage when page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, local-storage

There are multiple collapsible panels and a particular panel gets collapsed when a button placed on a that panel is clicked.This button is toggled as plus and minus icon when clicked over.Collapsed panels and button icon should remain in the same state on page refresh. Panel part is working fine but toggle button does not remain in the same state i.e. plus icon is toggled to minus icon on click but when clicked again it remains as minus icon only instead of changing back to plus icon. I am using localstorage for saving the state for both panel and button. But I am missing the right approach for button somewhere. I am new to jquery and tried all answers given here and on other platform but not able to make out the exact issue. Please help to point out what is going wrong. if need any other info,please let me know.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel panel-heading" style="height: 45px;">
<h4 class="text-center" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right: 10px;"></span>Name
<span data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{ template }}">
<span class="more-less pull-right" aria-hidden="true" id="{{ icon }}" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i></span>
</span>
</h4>
</div>
<div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="{{ template }}">
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><p class="lead"><b>Duration : </b> 1 Hour</p></div>
<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><h4 class="text-muted "><code>Module Topics</code></h4></div>
<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
</div>
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
    $(".more-less").click(function ()
    {
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus-sign').toggleClass('glyphicon-minus-sign');
        var active = $(this).attr('id');
        var activeclass = $(this).find('i').attr('class');
        var gicon= localStorage.gicon === undefined ? new Array() : JSON.parse(localStorage.gicon);
        if ($.inArray(active,gicon)==-1) //check that the element is not in the array
            gicon.push(active);
            gicon.push(activeclass);
        localStorage.gicon=JSON.stringify(gicon);
    });


    $(document).ready(function() {
    var gicon=localStorage.gicon === undefined ? new Array() : JSON.parse(localStorage.gicon); 
        for (var i in gicon){ 
            if ($("#"+gicon[i]).find('i').hasClass('glyphicon-plus-sign'))
            {
                $("#"+gicon[i]).html('<i  class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></i>');

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working example https://jsfiddle.net/sL2tmrsd/ - use this to test. 
I refactored your code.

Please keep in mind to never use `new Array()` use `[]` instead.

Stackoverflow's code snippet is not working with localStorage so don't bother clicking "Run code snippet".

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {

  
  function expandPanelOnInit() {
   var activePanel = localStorage.getItem('activePanel');
   
   // We exit function if activePanel is not set yet
   if (activePanel === null) {
    return;
   }

   $('a[aria-controls="' + activePanel + '"]')
    .removeClass('collapsed')
    .attr('aria-expanded', true)
    .find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus-sign glyphicon-minus-sign');
    
   $('#' + activePanel).addClass('in');
   
   
  }
  
  expandPanelOnInit();
        
        $('a[role="button"]').click(function() {
          var id = $(this).attr('aria-controls');
    var _thisIcon = $(this).find('i');
    
    localStorage.setItem('activePanel', id);
    
    
    
    $('#accordion i.glyphicon').not(_thisIcon)
   .removeClass('glyphicon-minus-sign')
   .addClass('glyphicon-plus-sign');
    
    _thisIcon.toggleClass('glyphicon-plus-sign glyphicon-minus-sign');
          
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes It worked..That's exactly what I was looking for ..Thanks a lot